# My chicken stock is a gelatinous mess. Is this normal? Can it be saved?

Tags: soup, stock, chicken-stock

I've been looking for a chicken soup with matzo balls recipe that would duplicate my grandma's (she died without passing on the recipe.) [This one](http://www.girlwithspoon.com/2010/01/homemade-chicken-stock.html) sounded like it would be close. I followed it to the letter, and let it cool in the fridge overnight so it would be easier to remove the fat.

When I took it out of the fridge, I was able to pull a solid layer of fat off the top, but the "soup" underneath is not liquid - it's gelatinous. Is this normal? If not, what did I do wrong? And is there any way to fix it? I had planned on giving jars of it to friends, but it looks pretty disgusting when cool, even if it does heat up correctly (which I'm not sure it does; it's reheating on the stove now.)

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/37355/14401 -- Yes, it is perfectly normal, and considered desirable.

Comment: If you've never seen that before, you're about to taste the best chicken soup you've ever had :)

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I panicked and posted without even searching. Bad. I'll put together my jars, and just tell everyone that's what it's supposed to look like when cool!